# Почему файл не видит переменную?

Tags: php, классы, функции, include

Есть файл с классом и функцией Profile.php:

```
<?php
class News
{
    public static function getNewsList() {
        $api = "123123123";

//Функция большая, это её начало.
```

Есть файл который по идее включает в себя код выше:

```
<?php
include_once ROOT. '/models/Profile.php';    
class ProfileController {

    public function actionIndex()
    {


        $newsList = News::getNewsList();

        echo $api; // Выдаёт ошибку:Notice: Undefined variable: api


        return true;
    }
```

Функция подключается, это сто процентов. А вот почему-то переменные не видит ... В чём проблема ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Область видимости переменной $api это функция getNewsList().
Если вам необходимо получить переменную в другом месте то вам необходимо в вынести её в отдельный метод, который её вернет. В классе News создать метод

```
public static function getApi() {
    $api = '123123123';
    return $api;
}
```

И далее вызывайте где вам необходимо

```
$api = News::getApi();
```

Comment: Коротко, понятно и эффективно.

Comment: А как вытащить отсюда много переменных ? Апи вытаскивается отлично, а что с другими делать ? Каждый раз перевызывать ?